# Shuffles vs direct sums of permutations

Tags: group-theory, permutations

A $(p,q)$-shuffle is a permutation of $p+q$ things that preserves the internal order of the first $p$ things and of the last $q$ things.  As remarked on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riffle_shuffle_permutation), since a $(p,q)$-shuffle is uniquely determined by the choice of the $p$ images of the first $p$ things, there are $\begin{pmatrix} p+q\\ p\end{pmatrix}  = \frac{(p+q)!}{p! q!}$ of them.  They are not a group; the product of two shuffles is not a shuffle.

The [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_and_direct_sums_of_permutations) of a permutation $\pi$ of $p$ things and a permutation $\sigma$ of $q$ things is a permutation of $p+q$ things that rearranges the first $p$ things among themselves according to $\pi$ and the last $q$ things among themselves according to $\sigma$.  This defines an injective (non-normal) group homomorphism $S_p \times S_q \hookrightarrow S_{p+q}$.  Note that $S_p \times S_q$ has cardinality $p!q!$, while $S_{p+q}$ has cardinality $(p+q)!$.

What exactly is the relationship between these two things?  It seems to me that the $(p,q)$-shuffles should be a set of canonical representatives for the cosets of $S_p\times S_q$ in $S_{p+q}$, and the cardinalities cited above bear that out.  In particular, any permutation of $p+q$ should decompose uniquely into the product of a $(p,q)$-shuffle and something in the image of $S_p\times S_q$.   If this is true, can anyone give a reference?  And is there any way to precisely characterize the "canonicalness" of these representatives?

Comment: All this works exactly as you wrote. Where are youhaving difficulties proving it?

Comment: In that case can you give a reference?  I can certainly prove it myself, but I would have expected it to be a standard fact, and I haven't found it mentioned anywhere.

Comment: As you wrote, There is a $(p,q)$ shuffle for each $p$-subset of $\{1,\dots,p+q\}$. The action of $S_{p+q}$ on the latter is transitive and clearly, $S_p\times S_q$ is the stabilizer of the subset $\{1,\dots,p\}$. This provides a bijection $S_{p+q}/S_p\times S_q\to\text{shuffles}_{p,q}$ and it is really obvious that in each coset there is exactly one shuffle.

Comment: No reference though?

Comment: You can look in Loday's book on cyclic homology, which works quite a bit with shuffles, or in Aguiar and Mahajan's book of species. But this is sort of an exercise, really :-|

Comment: I'd be happy to find it stated as an exercise.